# Storing arbitrary function calls across threads

Tags: multithreading, haskell, types, signals-slots

I'm trying to write a library aiming to reproduce Qt's threading semantics: signals can be connected to slots, and all slots execute in a known thread, so that slots tied to the same thread are threadsafe with regards to each other.

I have the following API:

```
data Signal a = Signal Unique a
data Slot a = Slot Unique ThreadId (a -> IO ())

mkSignal :: IO (Signal a)
mkSlot   :: ThreadId -> (Slot a -> a -> IO ()) -> IO (Slot a)

connect :: Signal a -> Slot a -> IO ()

-- callable from any thread
emit :: Signal a -> a -> IO ()

-- runs in Slot's thread as a result of `emit`
execute :: Slot a -> a -> IO ()
execute (Slot _ _ f) arg = f arg
```

The problem is getting from `emit` to `execute`. The argument needs to be stored at runtime somehow, and then an IO action performed, but I can't seem to get past the type checker.

The things I need:

1. Type safety: signals shouldn't be connected to slots expecting a different type.
2. Type-independence: there can be more than one slots for any given type (Perhaps this can be relaxed with newtype and/or TH).
3. Ease of use: since this is a library, signals and slots should be easy to create.

The things I've tried:

- [Data.Dynamic](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Dynamic.html): makes the whole thing really fragile, and I haven't found a way to perform a correctly-typed IO action on a `Dynamic`. There's [dynApply](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Dynamic.html#v%3adynApply), but it's pure.
- [Existential types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type): I need to execute the function passed to `mkSlot`, as opposed to an arbitrary function based on the type.
- [Data.HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList): I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, are you sure Slots really want to execute in a specific thread? It's easy to write thread-safe code in Haskell, and threads are very lightweight in GHC, so you're not gaining much by tying all event-handler execution to a specific Haskell thread.

Also, `mkSlot`'s callback doesn't need to be given the Slot itself: you can use [recursive do-notation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#recursive-do-notation) to bind the slot in its callback without adding the concern of tying the knot to `mkSlot`.

Anyway, you don't need anything as complicated as those solutions. I expect when you talk about existential types, you're thinking about sending something like `(a -> IO (), a)` through a `TChan` (which you mentioned using in the comments) and applying it on the other end, but you want the `TChan` to accept values of this type for any *a*, rather than just one specific *a*. The key insight here is that if you have `(a -> IO (), a)` and don't know what *a* is, the only thing you can do is apply the function to the value, giving you an `IO ()` — so we can just send those through the channel instead!

Here's an example:

```
import Data.Unique
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM

newtype SlotGroup = SlotGroup (IO () -> IO ())

data Signal a = Signal Unique (TVar [Slot a])
data Slot a = Slot Unique SlotGroup (a -> IO ())

-- When executed, this produces a function taking an IO action and returning
-- an IO action that writes that action to the internal TChan. The advantage
-- of this approach is that it's impossible for clients of newSlotGroup to
-- misuse the internals by reading the TChan or similar, and the interface is
-- kept abstract.
newSlotGroup :: IO SlotGroup
newSlotGroup = do
  chan <- newTChanIO
  _ <- forkIO . forever . join . atomically . readTChan $ chan
  return $ SlotGroup (atomically . writeTChan chan)

mkSignal :: IO (Signal a)
mkSignal = Signal <$> newUnique <*> newTVarIO []

mkSlot :: SlotGroup -> (a -> IO ()) -> IO (Slot a)
mkSlot group f = Slot <$> newUnique <*> pure group <*> pure f

connect :: Signal a -> Slot a -> IO ()
connect (Signal _ v) slot = atomically $ do
  slots <- readTVar v
  writeTVar v (slot:slots)

emit :: Signal a -> a -> IO ()
emit (Signal _ v) a = atomically (readTVar v) >>= mapM_ (`execute` a)

execute :: Slot a -> a -> IO ()
execute (Slot _ (SlotGroup send) f) a = send (f a)
```

This uses a `TChan` to send actions to the worker thread each slot is tied to.

Note that I'm not very familiar with Qt, so I may have missed some subtlety of the model. You can also disconnect Slots with this:

```
disconnect :: Signal a -> Slot a -> IO ()
disconnect (Signal _ v) (Slot u _ _) = atomically $ do
  slots <- readTVar v
  writeTVar v $ filter keep slots
  where keep (Slot u' _) = u' /= u
```

You might want something like `Map Unique (Slot a)` instead of `[Slot a]` if this is likely to be a bottleneck.

So, the solution here is to (a) recognise that you have something that's fundamentally based upon mutable state, and use a mutable variable to structure it; (b) realise that functions and IO actions are first-class just like everything else, so you don't have to do anything special to construct them at runtime :)

By the way, I suggest keeping the implementations of `Signal` and `Slot` abstract by not exporting their constructors from the module defining them; there are many ways to tackle this approach without changing the API, after all.

Comment: The main idea is that the slots executing in the *same* thread are threadsafe with regards to each other. It doesn't matter what kind of thread it is. And yes, I have my own event loop that does nothing but listens on a TChan and executes whatever comes through.

Comment: @GyörgyAndrasek: Ah, I see: *every* slot runs in the *same* thread, rather than every slot running in its own thread. I'm sceptical of whether this is a good thing — Haskell has very good threading support and with things like STM it's often harder to write thread-unsafe code than thread-safe code — but I'll amend my answer appropriately.

Comment: Not quite. You have groups of slots, executing in the thread of their group. In Qt, this is done with `object.moveToThread(thread)`, where slots are methods of the object. The effect is that you can cleanly communicate between e.g. a GUI thread and a recursive directory crawler thread, without spewing threading issues across the whole code base.

Comment: (Although this doesn't handle the case of moving an existing slot from one group to another, but you can easily build that on top by wrapping the SlotGroup in a TVar.)

Comment: @GyörgyAndrasek, if you want slots in the same thread/group to run atomically wrt each other, why not just run them in STM, or use an MVar lock on the slot group?

Comment: That was nicely done, reformulating the problem to the key idea and sketching out an implementation and all. :]

Comment: @bdonlan: Presumably they would like to cause side-effects in slot code, as event handlers often do; GHC has yet to implement the required time-machine semantics to allow `instance MonadIO STM` :) A lock on the slot group would work, but is probably no simpler than a dedicated thread reading a `TChan`. @C.A.McCann: Thanks! :)

Comment: @ehird: Exactly. My primary use case is doing file operations on a thread separate from the UI.